# Char Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I was told that `strdup` returns the address where the string is stored. So in the program I have mentioned, to print the string, I thought that I have to use the dereferencing operator `*`, but if I do that it prints only the first character and without using the dereferencing operator, I am getting the whole string. I can not wrap my head around when to use the dereferencing operator.

Same is with directly assigning the `const char`.

When I checked it with int, it prints the address and not the value. Why the difference.

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    char* num = strdup("Adam ");
    cout << num << endl ;
    char *n = "Eve ";
    cout << n << endl;

    int *m = (int*)670;
    cout << m << endl ;
    cout << *m << endl;
}
```

Comment: That's a feature of `cout`. It's designed to print `char` pointers as strings, and other kinds of pointers as addresses.

Comment: A `char` stores a single character. A string is a character sequence, so the type of a string is `char*`.

Comment: `cout << *m << endl` is undefined behaviour, as `m` contains the arbitrary pointer value `670` which most likely points nowhere. What output do you expect for your program?

Comment: `strdup` return a `char*` allocated with `malloc` so you need to `free` the pointer when you don't use it anymore

Answer (score 1):

In C there really are no strings. The address where the string is stored **is** the string.

It's confusing because in C++ there are strings, so you have C++ strings and C strings both of which are legal in a C++ program. If you have the address of a C++ string you really would have to use the dereference operator (as you do with an int).

Answer (score 1):

> to print the string, I thought that I have to use the dereferencing operator *

You thought wrong. `char*` is a pointer to a character. If you dereference a pointer to a character, the result is the character object that is pointed at.

> but if I do that it prints only the first character and without using the dereferencing operator, I am getting the whole string

This is because of how the overload of the stream insertion operator of a character stream that accepts a pointer to a character is specified to behave. The operator will assume that it is a pointer to the first character of a null terminated string, and the specified behaviour is to print the entire string.

> When I checked it with int, it prints the address

This is because the insert operator is not specified to print an entire null terminated character string when given a pointer to an integer. After all, a pointer to an integer won't be pointing to a character of a string.

There is no separate overload for pointers to integer. There is one overload that accepts all pointers (except character pointers, which have the separate overload): The overload for void pointers - all data pointers implicitly convert to void pointers. The specified behaviour of inserting a (other than character) pointer into a stream is to print the address that is being pointed at.

> Why the difference.

Because pointers to characters are special. In string processing contexts, they're nearly always assumed to be pointers to a first character of a null terminated string. This is an idiom/convention dating back to the C language, which C++ was originally derived from.

---

PS. `*m` has undefined behaviour, since you never created an `int` object at the address 670. Furthermore, the program leaks the memory that `strdup` allocated.